# im new to making discord bots with node.js, i am having trouble with an error, it says that message is not defined in line 14 and 18

Tags: node.js, discord.js

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client()
const prefix = '+';

client.once('ready' , () => {
    console.log('MemeStrifer is online')
});
client.on('message', message => {
    if(message.content.startsWith(prefix) ||message.author.bot) return;
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.lenght).split(/+/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if(command === 'blackhumour'){
        message.channel.send('What is the difference between a kid and a bowling ball? when you put your fingers in one it doesnt scream');
     } else if (command === 'sex') {
       message.channel.send('no you f***ing pervert');
     }
});

client.login('***');
```

Sorry if I am making any stupid errors, I just started yesterday by a YouTube video.

Comment: You closed the message event, `message` has no context because it's outside the callback function. I highly recommend you get the hang of JavaScript first.

Comment: `const args = message.content.slice(prefix.lenght).split(/+/);` has a problem tho, i can't manage to figure it out

Comment: If the current issue has been fixed and you now have a new issue, consider posting a new question. I recommend you check out [The Official Discord.JS Guide](https://discordjs.guide/)

Comment: it already was a problem since the start, i solved the problem at bracket 18, this is 14 now

Comment: See the discord [guide](https://discordjs.guide/#before-you-begin). Most of the problems and their solution is given.

Answer (score 0):

here,try this:

```
client.on('message', message =>{
if(message.content.startsWith(prefix) ||message.author.bot) return;
const args = message.content.slice(prefix.lenght).split(/+/);
const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
if(command === 'blackhumour'){
    message.channel.send('What is the difference between a kid and a bowling ball? when you put your fingers in one it doesnt scream');
  }  else if(command === 'sex'){
   message.channel.send('no you fucking pervert');
   }
  });
```